# How to select the value of `show global status like 'Com_stmt_pre%';`

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I need to read this value in a bash script so want to "select" the value but I'm not sure how. Currently I run `show global status like 'Com_stmt_pre%';` which returns:

[image]

But I need to actually select the value out.

The closest variable I've found is `SELECT variable_value FROM performance_schema.global_status WHERE  VARIABLE_NAME = 'Prepared_stmt_count';` but the values are different.

Answer (score 0):

A script method would be:

```
$ v=$(mysql --skip-column-names -B -e  'show global status like "Com_stmt_prepare"')
$ v="${v##*[:space:]}"
$ echo $v
0
```

Note: information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS is not in MySQL-8.0 so `show global status` needed to be used.

Comment: Unfortunately I get Unknown table GLOBAL_STATUS in information_schema wen running that.

Answer (score 0):

- To get the global status: `Select from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS`
- To get the global variable: `Select from information_schema.GLOBAL_VARIABLES`

```sql
# Equals `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'com_stmt_pre%';`
SELECT * FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS 
WHERE variable_name LIKE 'com_stmt_pre%';
```

Note: It could be different between those if your server is running

Comment: Unfortunately I get Unknown table GLOBAL_STATUS in information_schema when running that.

Comment: This last line of your answer seems to be incomplete. ...Running what?